# Highcharts > Positioning data labels between columns

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to show the % difference between the columns. 
The labels above the columns represent that bars total. The % between the columns show a % change between each bar. I have positioned the x-axis OK, but the y-axis values are difficult.  My aim is to:
**Align % values to 50% on the y-Axis (half the height of the chart) and in between the columns** so it shows a straight line of values. Currently these numbers are relative to the height of the bar column values.

http://jsfiddle.net/tellmehow/1sr9ab6d/15/

See an image here:

[image]

My code as follows.

```js
$(function(){
  var data = [1000,800,700,300,250,234,10,1,0,0];

  function percent(data) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i=0; i<data.length -1; i++) {
     if(data[i] === 0) {
       result[data[i]] = 100;
     } else {
       result[data[i]] = 100 - (data[i] - data[i +1]) * 100 / data[i];
     }
   }
   return result;
 } //percent

 $('#highcharts-panel').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      redraw: function(event) {
        refreshArrowPos();
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [{
      text: "various...",
    }]
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'whatever'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false,
    followTouchMove: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
    }, //col
    series: {
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      shadow:false,
      borderWidth:0,
      dataLabels:{
        useHTML: true,
        enabled:true,
        formatter:function() {
          var percents = percent(data);
          return (Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0) + "<div class='dataPercent'>" + (this.y == data[data.length - 1] ? '' : Highcharts.numberFormat(percents[this.y]) + '%' + "<div class='arrow'></div>") + "</div>");
        },
        style: {
          fontSize: "14px",
        }
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Total users',
    data: data,
  }],

}

  );


  function refreshArrowPos() {

    $('.dataPercent').each (function(){

      var colWidth = ($('#highcharts-panel').width() / data.length);    
      var colHeight = ($('#highcharts-panel').height() / data.length);

      $(this).css({ left: ($(this).position().left + (colWidth / 2) - ($(this).width() /　4 )) + 'px',
                    top: ($(this).position().top + (colHeight / 2)) + 'px'
                  }); //end css

      }); //dataPErcent fun

  } //refreshArrowPos

  refreshArrowPos();

});//highCharts Func
```

```html
 <div id="highcharts-pannel" class="funnelChart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding my image, I didn't have the status to add an image, but it explains things very clearly (I hope).

Comment: You say that the "y-axis values are difficult", but where would you ideally like it to be positioned? Are the positions for the one between the two first columns ok? Why not just place it statically just above the x-axis? Is your goal to align it with the top of the previous column?

Comment: yes, it was my goal to align it to the top of the previous column, but if we get 0 as a total value then this % goes beneath the x-axis.

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle for this? I guess you'd have to do a check if the y-position is below the x-axis, and if so set it right above the x-axis instead. Well described question by the way.

Comment: For me all labels are in the plotArea (above xAxis), which browser do you use that it's displayed incorrectly ?

Comment: Sebastian, @Ondkloss, I have updated my Fiddle to include the CSS and you can see my problem clearly now. http://jsfiddle.net/tellmehow/1sr9ab6d/15/ 
The arrow is relative to the bar value, and therefore will always appear below the x-axis in low values. I need to make sure they're relative to the x-axis, so maybe a static setting for these numbers i required??

Comment: @Sebastian, I modified my question, to make the values 50% on the y-Axis and keep the x-Axis set at in between the bars. If you have any feedback, it would be greatly appreciated.